# Limit number of associated records on DB level

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

Let's assume I have two tables `parents` and `children`. Naturally parents may have many children with one-to-many association. Is there any construct within MySQL or PostgreSQL which would allow to limit the number of associated objects, something like:

```
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
  REFERENCES parent(id)
  LIMIT 3
```

Does anything like this exists or do we need to have a custom trigger?

Comment: I think you need to have custom triggers for MySQL. I'm not aware of such a feature.

Comment: @VMai Is correct there is no such feature like it. You have to use custom triggers for achieving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the definition of foreign keys. I would solve that by adding a sequential number for each child per parent like this (code for **PostgreSQL**, the principal is standard SQL):

```
CREATE TABLE child (
   child_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
 , parent_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES parent
 , child_nr  int NOT NULL
 , CHECK (child_nr BETWEEN 1 AND 3)
 , UNIQUE (parent_id, child_nr)
);
```

This way you can have children 1 through 3 for each parent or some or none of those. But no others.

Since you have a natural PK with `(parent_id, child_nr)` now, you could drop the surrogate PK column `child_id`. But I like to have a single-column surrogate PK for almost every table ...

You *could* use a trigger to limit the number, which checks how many children are there already before inserting a new one. But you'd run into concurrency issues, and it's more expensive, less reliable, easier to circumvent and vendor-specific.

#### How to manage `child_nr`?

The RDBMS just enforces (reliably) that no illegal state can ever exist in the table. How you figure out the next `child_nr` is up to you. Many different approaches are possible.

For just three children, you *could* insert all children automatically when creating a parent (with a trigger, a rule or in your application). With given `(parent_id, child_nr)` and additional columns NULL.

Then you would only allow `UPDATE` and not `INSERT` or `DELETE` for the child table (`GRANT` / `REVOKE`), or even make sure with another trigger, so that superusers cannot circumvent it. Make the FK to `parent` with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, so children die with the parent automatically.

#### Alternative

Somewhat less reliable, but cheaper: Keep a running count of children in the `parent` table and restrict it to be `<= 3`. Update it with every change in the `child` table with triggers. Be sure to cover all possible ways to alter data in the child table.

Comment: I love the idea! Few questions - how is the `child_nr` column to be handled? I believe it would need to be on the application level?

Comment: @BroiSatse: The RDBMS just enforces (reliably) that you can't insert anything illegal. How you figure out the next `child_nr` is up to you. I added one suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, awesome answer. I think I will dig a little more around the alternative you posted. I am rails developer and there is already a feature taking care of this extra counter column - need to check how reliable it is on the db level though. Again - thanks a lot.

Comment: @BroiSatse: it might be worth mentioning that this approach will not work with MySQL due to its lack of check constraints.